# How to run only selective test cases in Maven

Tags: maven, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

Scenario:

I have about 50 test cases,I want to run only 20 of them.How to achieve this in Maven

Comment: Are you using testng.xml inside maven ?

Comment: yes i am using testng inside maven and i will configure that testng name in <suiteXmlFile>

Comment: just configure groups in your testng.xml file

Comment: Why do you need an testng.xml file ?

Comment: @vigneshvicks your question is suitable for TestNG tag, You are using it. Testing tag is common for testing stuff. Rollback it for TestNG tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can go for **grouping** which is available in **testng**. Make one set of group which will contain those 20 test methods and then run that particular group.

Let's say for your scenario :

```
public class Test1 {
  @Test(groups = { "functest"})
  public void testMethod1() {
  }

  @Test(groups = {"functest"} )
  public void testMethod2() {
  }

  @Test(groups = { "functest" })
  public void testMethod3() {
  }
}
```

And Invoking TestNG with the help of Maven like this :

```
<test name="Test1">
  <groups>
    <run>
      <include name="functest"/>
    </run>
  </groups>
  <classes>
    <class name="example1.Test1"/>
  </classes>
</test>
```

This will be done in your `testng.xml` file.

For more about groups can be found [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups)

Another work around would be to go with `@Test(enabled = false)` for methods which you do not want to run with your current configuration. But that would be tedious job to do.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your question is a step by step process:

Initially,using "groups" annotation attributes you could group the test cases which you want to run  like below:

Example:

```
@Test(groups={"groupname"})
```

and then in the TestNG.xml file to run the particular group test cases:

```
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
  <test name="Test">
    <groups>
    <run>
         <include name="Smoke" />
    </run>
    </groups>
```

Once, this is done maven is just a build tool and it makes build consistent with another project.

Need to follow Maven build cycle:

1)validate

2)complie

3)test

4)package

5)verify

6)install

7)deploy.

if you face any  hurdles in Grouping or in maven life cycle steps let me know I will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it,

- As explained by **@cruisepandey** by using Group call

  Limitation: It will be static group call, So it means everytime it will call all groups if you don't want any single one. And you need to manage it manually everytime.
- By defined specified Test in TestNG.XML suite,

To execute selected Test in Maven, You need to define target Test in POM.XML(Which can do 
 by defining class or testng.xml single suite)

**Recommended to use .XML file to Run even it as TestNG suite, if you do not want to run it using Maven Test**

How to create selected TestNG suite,

### **TestNG.XMl Suite Definition:**

**By Class:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
    <classes>
      <class name="package1.test1"/>
      <class name="package2.test2"/>
      <class name="package6.test6"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

If you wish to include package, you can do it as :

**By Package:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
        <test name="TesteEmo">
            <packages>
                <package name="package4"></package>
            </packages>
        </test> <!-- Test -->
    </parameter>
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**Call .XML File in to POM:**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>TestNG.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```